# Proper way to create an integer jsonb nested key index

Tags: postgresql, index, json, cast

I have the following index I'm trying to modify by declaring the `poLineNumberInteger` key as numeric/integer instead of text. This is valid syntax:

```
CREATE INDEX ubdrecord_jsonb_extract_path_text_idx
  ON public.ubdrecord
  USING btree
  (jsonb_extract_path_text(metadata, VARIADIC ARRAY['lineInfo'::text, 'poLineNumberInteger'::text]));
```

However, if I try to modify the "text" to "numeric" in the above statement, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "poLineNumberInteger"
LINE 4: ...h_text(metadata, VARIADIC ARRAY['lineInfo'::text, 'poLineNum...
                                                             ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "poLineNumberInteger"
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 158
```

The question is, how to modify this create statement to declare the key as numeric without having to cast? Also, we have to use the jsonb_extract_path_text wrapper. Even without it, not sure how to appropriately modify the syntax.

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE ubdrecord
(
  id uuid NOT NULL,
  senderduns character varying(256),
  sendername character varying(256),
  receiverduns character varying(256),
  receivername character varying(256),
  messagetype character varying(100),
  metadata jsonb,
  sourceid uuid NOT NULL,
  sourcetype character varying(10),
  originaltime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  createdtime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  processingmode integer,
  ubdversion character varying(20),
  unitofmeasure character varying(256),
  quantity numeric,
  active boolean,
  documentid character varying(256),
  CONSTRAINT pk_ubdrecord1 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

*** Query ***

```
select "receivername", "unitofmeasure", "ubdversion", "processingmode", "metadata", "senderduns", "active", "createdtime", "sourcetype",
"documentid", "id", "sendername", "messagetype", "quantity", "sourceid", "originaltime", "receiverduns"
from "ubdrecord"
where
(jsonb_extract_path_text("metadata",'lineInfo','poLineNumberInteger') = '11123')
order by "createdtime"
desc limit 1
```

*** Query Explain Plan Results ***

```
'Limit  (cost=0.43..311.36 rows=1 width=4046) (actual time=206530.018..206530.018 rows=0 loops=1)'
'  ->  Index Scan Backward using createdtimeindex on ubdrecord  (cost=0.43..5593950.48 rows=17991 width=4046) (actual time=206530.015..206530.015 rows=0 loops=1)'
'        Filter: (jsonb_extract_path_text(metadata, VARIADIC '{lineInfo,poLineNumberInteger}'::text[]) = '11123'::text)'
'        Rows Removed by Filter: 3598344'
'Planning time: 22.892 ms'
'Execution time: 206530.082 ms'
```

*** Created Time Index ***

```
CREATE INDEX createdtimeindex
  ON public.ubdrecord
  USING btree
  (createdtime);
```

The explain plan looks like maybe the issue in with the sort column. However, the sort comes back fast (~100-200 ms) for querying on other jsonb values within that metadata block.

*** \d ubdrecord ***

```
Time: 0.113s
summarist> \d ub
Did not find any relation named ub.
Time: 0.145s
summarist> \d ubdrecord
+----------------+-----------------------------+-------------+
| Column         | Type                        | Modifiers   |
|----------------+-----------------------------+-------------|
| id             | uuid                        |  not null   |
| senderduns     | character varying(256)      |             |
| sendername     | character varying(256)      |             |
| receiverduns   | character varying(256)      |             |
| receivername   | character varying(256)      |             |
| messagetype    | character varying(100)      |             |
| metadata       | jsonb                       |             |
| sourceid       | uuid                        |  not null   |
| sourcetype     | character varying(50)       |             |
| originaltime   | timestamp without time zone |  not null   |
| createdtime    | timestamp without time zone |  not null   |
| processingmode | integer                     |             |
| ubdversion     | character varying(20)       |             |
| unitofmeasure  | character varying(256)      |             |
| quantity       | numeric                     |             |
| active         | boolean                     |             |
| documentid     | character varying(256)      |             |
+----------------+-----------------------------+-------------+
Indexes:
    "pk_ubdrecord" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "createdtimeindex" btree (createdtime)
    "deliverynotelinenumberintegerindex" btree (jsonb_extract_path_text(metadata, VARIADIC ARRAY['deliveryNoteInfo'::text, 'deliveryNoteLineNumberInteger'::text]))
    "deliverynotenumberindex" btree (jsonb_extract_path_text(metadata, VARIADIC ARRAY['deliveryNoteInfo'::text, 'deliveryNoteNumber'::text]))
    "documentidindex" btree (documentid)
    "invoicenumberindex" btree (jsonb_extract_path_text(metadata, VARIADIC ARRAY['invoiceInfo'::text, 'invoiceNumber'::text]))
    "messagetypeindex" btree (messagetype)
    "polinenumberindex" btree (jsonb_extract_path_text(metadata, VARIADIC ARRAY['lineInfo'::text, 'poLineNumber'::text]))
    "polinenumberintegerindex" btree (jsonb_extract_path_text(metadata, VARIADIC ARRAY['lineInfo'::text, 'poLineNumberInteger'::text]))
    "ponumberindex" btree (jsonb_extract_path_text(metadata, VARIADIC ARRAY['lineInfo'::text, 'poNumber'::text]))
    "processingmodeindex" btree (processingmode)
    "receiverindex" btree (receiverduns)
    "salesorderlinenumberindex" btree (jsonb_extract_path_text(metadata, VARIADIC ARRAY['salesOrderInfo'::text, 'salesOrderLineNumber'::text]))
    "salesorderlinenumberintegerindex" btree (jsonb_extract_path_text(metadata, VARIADIC ARRAY['salesOrderInfo'::text, 'salesOrderLineNumberInteger'::text]))
    "salesordernumberindex" btree (jsonb_extract_path_text(metadata, VARIADIC ARRAY['salesOrderInfo'::text, 'salesOrderNumber'::text]))
    "senderindex" btree (senderduns)
    "shipmentnumberindex" btree (jsonb_extract_path_text(metadata, VARIADIC ARRAY['shipmentInfo'::text, 'shipmentNumber'::text]))
```

*** Similar query ***

```
select "receivername", "unitofmeasure", "ubdversion", "processingmode", "metadata", "senderduns", "active", "createdtime", "sourcetype",
"documentid", "id", "sendername", "messagetype", "quantity", "sourceid", "originaltime", "receiverduns" from "ubdrecord"
where
(jsonb_extract_path_text("metadata",'lineInfo','poLineNumber') = '11124124124124')
order by "createdtime" desc limit 1;
```

*** Similar query plan ***

```
'Limit  (cost=3776.77..3776.77 rows=1 width=4046) (actual time=0.053..0.053 rows=0 loops=1)'
'  ->  Sort  (cost=3776.77..3779.20 rows=970 width=4046) (actual time=0.050..0.050 rows=0 loops=1)'
'        Sort Key: createdtime DESC'
'        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB'
'        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on ubdrecord  (cost=19.95..3771.92 rows=970 width=4046) (actual time=0.043..0.043 rows=0 loops=1)'
'              Recheck Cond: (jsonb_extract_path_text(metadata, VARIADIC '{lineInfo,poLineNumber}'::text[]) = '11124124124124'::text)'
'              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on polinenumberindex  (cost=0.00..19.70 rows=970 width=0) (actual time=0.039..0.039 rows=0 loops=1)'
'                    Index Cond: (jsonb_extract_path_text(metadata, VARIADIC '{lineInfo,poLineNumber}'::text[]) = '11124124124124'::text)'
'Planning time: 0.205 ms'
'Execution time: 0.091 ms'
```

The real head scratcher for me is why the first query doesn't seem to use the index/sortkey as this other one does. The index for both fields look the same to me.

Comment: as a side note, we don't use varchar(x) in PostgreSQL unless the spec requires it. It's just a text field with a length check (ie., slower). You probably just want `text`. We also don't double quote identifiers, ever (it makes them case-sensitive).

Comment: by varchar you mean character varying columns?

Comment: yes, those should likely all be text, and quantity should likely be something int-ish, unless you need fractional quantities. Anyway, So the only index you're using in that query is the `Index Scan Backward` for the limit. That's horrible. Can you paste the exact result of `\d ubdrecord`

Comment: Added that and a similar query/queryplan that doesn't go the Index Scan Backward route and comes back within a few milliseconds. Can't figure out the reason for the differences based on the index construction

Comment: did you `ANALZYE ubdrecord` after you created the index?

Comment: I just did. Says query returned successfully. Stupid question. What does that do, exactly?

Comment: try your slow query again.. anything change?

Answer (score 1):

> The question is, how to modify this create statement to declare the key as numeric without having to cast?

You can not. From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

[image]

## Addressing

The argument type is `text[]`. SQL Arrays, like path_elems, are strictly typed and SQL does not have type unions so there is neither a `text|numeric` type-union, nor a `TextOrNumeric` type. If you're addressing a deep heterogeneous structure of arrays and objects you need to use `->` and `->>`.

## Return type

You can see above, the return type of `jsonb_extract_path_text` is simply `text`. You must cast. There is also `jsonb_extract_path` but it's return type is fixed to jsonb. What you would need is `jsonb_extract_path_numeric` and you're not likely to get that. Even if someone implemented it, you'd still have to cast if you wanted to store it as an interger.

Keep in mind, for the purposes of indexing, this casting is only done when the row is written or the column is updated and it's very fast.

See also,

- [*Why does a JSON element return text when it's not text?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/168029/2639)

Comment: Okay, thanks. The problem is we're trying to create an index on that key and not getting any performance gain when trying to search for a value that doesn't exist. The ONLY difference between this key and the others (that return within ms if a non-existent value is queried) is currently the others are string value types.

Comment: @daniel9x past the table structure, query, and query plan.

Comment: Please find the question updated with the information you requested. Thanks for all your help so far.