# Going JavaScript to PostgreSQL and back!

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion

In JavaScript we work with nested/complex objects.
In PostgreSQL we have composite types and JSONB.

However, converting between JS types and PG types is not straightforward.

I am currently using JSONB, however I do not like the fact that I need to also cast JSONB fields to text (using ->> or #>> operators) then cast text to the desired PG native type (e.g. ::int4).

I wish that PG supports some kind of a native arbitrary object type like JS.

Any thoughts or better ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: I've voted to close this because I have self-answered another question where I was preoccupied with the same problem and had discovered the reason for it and why the json operators return text only: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/168029/2639

Comment: The question is more than json. I am asking for other alternatives?

Comment: There are no alternatives for the reasons specified on the linked question. It's not an implementation drawback. JSON is structureless. You'd have to impose the structure on the JSON in order to ensure that a value is not an int in one column, and a text field in another. When you do that, it ceases to be JSON. So just ignore the internal representation and get used to casting. There is no theoretical way around it.

Comment: There is no theoretical way around it (shy of implementing actual type inference).